# Closure-compiler param type Object.<string, *> doesn't works as expected

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

What would be the correct way to annotate the types of options that I could pass through an object as a function argument? Example:

```
/**
 * test() function can receive all type of options.
 * @param {Object.<string, *>} options
 * @expose
 */
function test(options) {
    if(typeof options.set !== "undefined") {
        alert(options.set);
    }

    if(typeof options.callback !== "undefined") {
        options.callback.apply(this, []);
    }
}
```

How I can define something like it ... ?

```
/**
 * @param {Object.<string, *>} options
 *     @param {Object.<string, *>} options.set
 *     @param {function(... [*])}  options.callback
 */
```

If I not does nothing, the compiler return an error like:

```
script.js:28: WARNING - Property callback never defined on Object.<string, *>
                  options.callback.apply(this, []);
                  ^
```

Usage method:

```
java -jar "compiler.jar" 
    --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS 
    --warning_level VERBOSE 
    --js "script.js" 
    --js_output_file "script.min.js"
```

Comment: Have you tried the most simple option: `@param {*} options` ?

Comment: I like to specify exactly what is each option. I'm thinking to use an `@interface`.

Comment: The correct options are to either fully define it as an `interface` or other type, or to use the record type annotations. It depends a lot on where options comes from and how it is created.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [record type](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#records):

```
@param {{set: Object, callback: function}} options
```

Comment: Correct - just don't forget that the record type options will still be subject to renaming.

Comment: also optional parameters are declared by including "undefined" in the parameter type.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify each option exactly you can do it like this:

```
/**
 * @param {{row: number, field: string, callback: function(string) }} options
 */
```

So you can declare object structure, including types, details are [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler).

Answer (score -1):

Just need to create a new variable and set it as a `@constructor`, `@expose`ing all this methods, like:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
var TestOptions = function() {
    /**
     * @type {Object.<string, *>}
     * @expose
     */
    this.set;

    /**
     * @type {function(... [*])}
     * @expose
     */
    this.callback;
};
```

After I just need set this as `@param` type, like:

```
/**
 * test() function can receive all type of options.
 * @param {TestOptions} options
 * @expose
 */
function test(options) {
    /* ... */
}
```

`TestOptions` will not be on `script.min.js` because I never used `new` on it.

Comment: Ouch don't use `@expose` like that. You invalidate all of the renaming and dead code elimination.

Comment: On my case is essential, because I'm build a library. So I need export this names, once that user will have it on documentation.

Comment: `@expose` is now deprecated. Authors should migrate their code to use `@export` or `@nocollapse` as appropriate.